Wall pulling away from moulding - unsure how to fix
enter image description hereI live in a craftsman built in 1920. I have an archway between my dining room and kitchen. It's unclear to me if it is original (would think it is) or if it was added later. The wall is pulling away from the moulding. It doesn't appear to be the moulding pulling from the wall, as the moulding has not warped and its still firmly attached to the ceiling. I've gone up into the attic to see if I could reattach from above, but the area is not open. Does anyone know how I might go about fixing this?

What's happening on the opposite side of the archway?

Is the wall straight or is it bowed?

Opposite side of the archway is completely straight. The wall definitely dips in away from the moulding and does not make a right angle where it meets the moulding.
